# How do I write an “OR” statement for MS Access?

Tags: validation, rule

Add a validation rule for the Level fiesld to store only values equal to 1 or 2

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-validation-rule-to-validate-data-in-a-field-HA010096312.aspx#BM5

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do it is:

```
  fiesld  In ("1", "2")
```

or

```
fiesld = 1 OR fiesld = 2
```

You didn't say the datatype of fiesld, so I used string in the first example and int in the second.